# Rails3 - how to process a filter after request sent to browser

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, filter, flush

I'm doing some custom caching of requests, and I'd like to do the slow saving-to-disk step after the response has already been sent to the server.

A standard after_filter runs before the response is sent to the client still.

Depending upon how the rails system works, perhaps this is imposible because it only sends back data when it's completely done processing the request.

From some older questions I've found, it seems a Rack middleware might be the answer, but none of the examples seem remotely related, like: https://github.com/rack/rack/wiki/List-of-Middleware

I'd also need access to the @response and params objects, but I think thats possible.

Thanks!

Comment: I have'nt tried by myself but this article might be your help: http://bibwild.wordpress.com/2011/11/14/multi-threading-in-rails-activerecord-3-0-3-1/ In short: you have to use Thread

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is something I can't understand about your goal.

If a cache is *a component that transparently stores data so that future requests for that data can be served faster*, your should worry to make the cached content available to the future requests as soon as possible, even if it means asking for the first request to wait some ms for its response to be sent.

If writing to disk is considered too slow in your context, you can try to engage one of the other caching backends Rails supports.

You could also add a background job with [Resque](http://github.com/defunkt/resque) or [delayed_job](http://github.com/collectiveidea/delayed_job); that job will take care of creating you cache and will be asynchronous to the response. But again the purpose of caching will be missed along with the cached content.

Comment: fastest != most common.  So my thought was that I'd rather have a 1% chance of another user requesting the same page in the 50ms it'd take to write the document, than ALWAYS have the 1st user wait the 50ms.

Comment: Ask yourself how many users will benefit the cache. Better, ask your logs. i.e. If you cache the page for 1 minutes, every minute someone will have to wait 50ms; how many users will hit the cached version? zero? a dozen? an hundred?

Comment: Whether or not to cache is kind-of a separate question.  And it's certainly fast enough, but every little bit could be nicer :)  Hardly any liklyhood of anyone hitting the cached copy during that 20ms vs the following week, but you make good points still, thanks.